# Get a tasks leaf

Tags: mysql

using MySQL, I want to return a list of tasks leaf in a table like this

```
ID  |  ID_TASK_PARENT  | TASK_NAME
---------------------------------------------
 1  |            NULL  | task level 1
 2  |               1  | task child level 2
 3  |               2  | task child level 3
 4  |            NULL  | task level 1
 5  |               4  | task child level 2
 6  |               5  | task child level 3
 7  |               5  | task child level 3
```

Now, it's possible with one query get the ID's of all leaf tasks from father task id?

Example:

```
ID = 1 --> result ID 3

ID = 4 --> result ID 6,7
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know that there will always be exactly 3 levels of nesting? Are you only interested in leaves at level 3?

Comment: unfortunately i don't know before

Answer (score 0):

If you always have three levels of nesting, and you only want level three in the output, this will work:

```
select one.id,three.id 
from leaves one 
join leaves two 
on one.id=two.id_task_parent 
join leaves three
on two.id = three.id_task_parent;
```

This assumes that your table is called "leaves". The way it works is by doing two self-joins using id<->id_task_parent. But it won't work if you want to report leaves at level two, or levels below 3, because mysql needs to be told about each join individually.

Comment: unfortunately i have more then 3 level

Answer (score 0):

I am affraid there is no good single query doing what you want.

I would suggest either using stored procedure for this task, using temporary table and loops (If you want I could suggest such procedure), or modify a bit the tasks table.

If there is a possibility to add ID_TASK_ROOT:

```
ID  |  ID_TASK_PARENT  | ID_TASK_ROOT | TASK_NAME
-------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |            NULL  |            1 | task level 1
 2  |               1  |            1 | task child level 2
 3  |               2  |            1 | task child level 3
 4  |            NULL  |            4 | task level 1
 5  |               4  |            4 | task child level 2
 6  |               5  |            4 | task child level 3
 7  |               5  |            4 | task child level 3
```

Then you could use query:

```
SELECT      t1.ID
    FROM    tasks t1
LEFT JOIN   tasks t2
        ON  t2.ID_TASK_PARENT = t1.ID
    WHERE   t2.ID IS NULL
        AND t1.ID_TASK_ROOT = ?;
```